# Make css nth-child() only affect visible

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

Is there a way to only affect visible elements with this css?

```
table.grid tr.alt:nth-child(odd)
{
    background:#ebeff4;
}

table.grid tr.alt:nth-child(even)
{
    background:#ffffff;
}
```

If i use a `$('select some tr:s').hide()` that hides some of the rows i get a mix of odd and even styling but all in a mixup.

Comment: Have you considered reapplying the CSS after the $().hide() using $('.alt:visible:even') and $('alt:visible:odd')?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I ended up using the solution Rodaine suggested in his comment, after the show/hide i do this:

```
$('.alt:visible:odd').css('background', '#EBEFF4');
$('.alt:visible:even').css('background', '#FFFFFF');
```

In my case the setting of background broke my hover, this was solved with `!important` to make the hover background stick.

```
table.grid tr.hover:hover
{
    cursor:pointer;
    background:#D2E0E9 !important;    
}
```

Comment: Using !important in production environnment is not a good habit to have. If you end up using !important, it means the solution may be a bit more complicated, but it exists. In that case, you want to apply classes with jquery to still be able to hover without !important : http://codepen.io/gfra/pen/nFrEc

Comment: Sometimes when using external libraries you don't have any choice in using "!important"

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers support the CSS Selectors Level 4 syntax like this:

```css
:nth-child(2n of .visible){
    ...
}
```

Will take only even elements of those that have the `visible` class.

More info:

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/css-ui/css-nth-child-of-s

https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/

Answer (score -2):

Another option would be to apply a class to the visible elements when hiding the others. Apply nth-child to this class (which is only applied to the visible elements.)

You don't have to use an !important tag to keep your hover-background in this case.

Comment: That's not possible, unfortunately: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428676/nth-child-doesnt-respond-to-class

Answer (score -5):

You could do:

```
$('some_selector tr:visible').hide()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It was not the hiding that was my problem.