# Select one out of of three div elements with the same class name

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I have three small div sections with the same class name(box) and I want to select the second one so I can select another p-Tag etc.

So far this is what I tried :

```
var select = document.querySelectorAll('.clearfix box box');
```

Of course, how this is written is wrong and I have no other ideas.

Html :

```
<div class="box">
  <p>Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo,fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus
    ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <p>Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus
    ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <p>Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus
    ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add the html to the question please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the second match with QuerySelector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22902447/how-to-get-the-second-match-with-queryselector)

Comment: Thanks for the answers everyone, however now I should replace the value of the p-Tag with some other text, how do I do that?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the elements by using the class selector and then get the second one from the selected elements:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.clearfix .box')[1];
```

Here, the `document.querySelectorAll` will return the `div`s with class `box` and then `[1]` will get the second one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I added my HTML in there take a look, basically .clearfix is the parent of both of those divs so thats what I tried there. Btw I dont understand what you mean, should I treat class as an attribute you mean?!

Answer (score 1):

With your html is setup like this, you can use the selector

```
.clearfix .box:nth-child(2)
```

This will get the second div in `clearfix` with a class containing `box`

```js
let select = document.querySelector('.clearfix .box:nth-child(2)')
let p = document.createElement('p')
p.textContent = 'New p element'
select.appendChild(p)
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
  <div class="box"><p>I am div 1</p></div>
  <div class="box"><p>I am div 2</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you tried this:

```
var select = document.getElementsByClassName("box")[1]
```

**getElementsByClassName** selects all classes named box in the document

**[1]** selects the second object (the index for the first object is 0)