# How can I console.log the second li element using javascript onclick

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```html
<h3>Shirts</h3>
<ul id='list'>
    <li>Biker Jacket</li>
    <li>Mens Shirt</li>
</ul>
```

I need to get console.log out the second li element. I tried the code below but I was only able to access the first li element

```js
document.querySelector("li").onclick = () => {
    console.log("Biker Jacket");
};
```

Comment: Use this selector: `ul>li:nth-child(2)`

Comment: **document.querySelectorAll('li')[1]** will select the second occurrence of `li` as it is 0-based.

Comment: If a question gets 5 answers within the first 5 minutes, you know that you didn't research enough.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22902447/how-to-get-the-second-match-with-queryselector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `querySelectorAll()` method instead and target the second `li` element like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#list li")[1].onclick = () => {
  console.log("Biker Jacket");
};
```

```html
<h3>Shirts</h3>
<ul id='list'>
    <li>Biker Jacket</li>
    <li>Mens Shirt</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried different iterations and locations for the [1], had no clue you could pass #list li through but it worked perfect. Much thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `querySelectorAll[1]` for the second one:

```js
document.querySelector("li").onclick = () => {
    console.log("Biker Jacket");
};
document.querySelectorAll("li")[1].onclick = () => {
    console.log("Mens Shirt");
};
```

```html
<h3>Shirts</h3>
<ul id='list'>
    <li>Biker Jacket</li>
    <li>Mens Shirt</li>
</ul>
```

And since this seems like you want to `console.log` the text content of the clicked list item, you could do this:

```js
function showText(elem) {
  console.log(elem.innerText);
}
document.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(li => li.addEventListener("click", () => showText(li)));
```

```html
<h3>Shirts</h3>
<ul id='list'>
  <li>Biker Jacket</li>
  <li>Mens Shirt</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the element using this onclick of the li and print its text using textContent

```js
function a(e)
{
console.log(e.textContent)
}
```

```html
<h3>Shirts</h3>
<ul id='list'>
    <li onclick="a(this)">Biker Jacket</li>
    <li onclick="a(this)">Mens Shirt</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:nth-child(x)` pseudo selector to get the element at position `x` like this:

```js
document.querySelector("ul#list > li:nth-child(2)").onclick = () => {
    console.log("Biker Jacket");
};
```

```html
<h3>Shirts</h3>
<ul id='list'>
    <li>Biker Jacket</li>
    <li>Mens Shirt</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to select it:

```
const item = document.querySelector("ul>li:nth-child(2)")
```

or

```
const item = document.querySelectorAll('#list li')[1]
```

or if it's just the last thing of any list you need:

```
const items = document.querySelectorAll('#list li');
const item = items[items.length-1];
```

When you have your item selected add a click handler to it:

```
item.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  console.log(this.innerText);
});
```