# How to apply alternate color but only to those elements having a specific data attribute

Tags: html, css

I want to make `li` element in alternate color but only those have a attribute `data-filetype="image".`

As soon as I add a new `li` without adding `data-filetype attribute`, my color sequence fails.

Link to JSBin is [**here**](http://jsbin.com/suwalobe/2/edit)

**HTML Code:**

```
<ul> 
 <li data-filetype="image">PNG Image</li><!-- It should be RED -->
 <li data-filetype="image">PNG Image</li><!-- It should be ORANGE -->
 <li>Normal Link</li><!-- After adding this li color sequence breaks -->
 <li data-filetype="image">PNG Image</li><!-- It should be RED -->
 <li data-filetype="image">PNG Image</li><!-- It should be ORANGE -->
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul li[data-filetype="image"]:nth-child(2n){color:orange}
ul li[data-filetype="image"]:nth-child(2n+1){color:red}
```

Comment: but is there any alternative way?

Comment: Don't think so with pure css

Comment: No, you cannot do this with CSS as the `nth-child/nth-of type` **only** applies to elements (with a common parent) and is not related to classes or any other attributes. See - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428676/nth-child-doesnt-respond-to-class

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery you can get the alternate Row color even if extra element added. Have a look at **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/suwalobe/3/edit)**.

/*JQuery Code*/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("li[data-filetype='image']:even").css({'color':'red'});
$("li[data-filetype='image']:odd").css({'color':'blue'});
$("li:not([data-filetype='image'])").css({'color':'white'});
});
```

Comment: This works, but I am looking for CSS solution. Now the question is that if its working through JQuery then why its not working using CSS only.