# How do I start the counting of the nth-child selector only with class "box special" not just "box"?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to make some boxes have different properties based on whether they're the odd or even number box in the group but only for a selector of multiple classes: But it's including the original `box` class's object despite it not being in the CSS selector for nth-child:

http://jsfiddle.net/wLx67r83/

```
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box special">1</div>
<div class="box special">1</div>

.box
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

.box.special:nth-child(odd)
{
    background-color: red;
}

.box.special:nth-child(even)
{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

The third box should be blue, but it's red! And the second should be red, but it's blue!

Comment: Because it's `nth-child` of the parent, not the `nth-child` of the class.

Comment: @Axel thank you. Is there a solution for using css to check its odd/even location in a group of siblings?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`nth-child` is counting from the parent's child nodes. The correct answer is `nth-of-type`:

```
.box.special:nth-of-type(odd)
{
    background-color: red;
}

.box.special:nth-of-type(even)
{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: But this produces the exact same results as your original fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/wLx67r83/2/

Comment: @Axel oddly, you're right. It works in my own web page but not on jsfiddle! Why?

Comment: No idea, but `nth-child` and `nth-of-type` both behave similar in that it counts from the parent.  What you're wanting is a `nth-of-class`, [but that doesn't exist in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5428766/1332068).  Better to wrap the special divs in their own parent div to guarantee the correct results.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the even/odd around in the css.

http://jsfiddle.net/wLx67r83/6/

```
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box special">1</div>
<div class="box special">1</div>

.box
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

.special:nth-child(even)
{
    background-color: red;
}

.box.special:nth-child(odd)
{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Edit: Or you can choose the formula option 
http://jsfiddle.net/wLx67r83/28/

```
.special:nth-child(2n+0)
{
    background-color: red !important;
}
.special:nth-child(2n+3)
{
    background-color: blue !important;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't fix the problem. There could be an additional `<div class="box">1</div>` added to the beginning which would make your solution wrong again. The problem is how to start counting from the first ".special"?

Comment: His solution actually does work, unless it's important for the first `.special` class to be red: http://jsfiddle.net/wLx67r83/14/

Comment: @Axel it does not work. You just happened to make that second group start on an even number. You can see the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/wLx67r83/22/

Comment: Can you use a formula like (an + b), does it have to be even and odd?  e.g http://jsfiddle.net/wLx67r83/28/