# Why pseudo-elements are not working well with ng-repeat?

Tags: css, angularjs, pseudo-element

I have the ng-repeat directive on my div `<div ng-repeat="tab in tabs" class="test"></div>`

In my css I have this:

```
.test {margin-right:1%}
.test:nth-child(4n) {margin-right:0}
```

The `nth-child(4n)` is not working with my ng-repeat but if I manually put my div without the ng-repeat it works like a charm.
(It's the same with all nth-child combination.

So what did I miss ?

**EDIT:** My case concerns the use of the ng-repeat combine with nth-child pseudo-element

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT 2**
This post is old but the problem as the last comment say, is that there is some ng-show.. It was obvious, no excuses.

Comment: possible duplicate of [nth-child doesn't respond to class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428676/nth-child-doesnt-respond-to-class)

Comment: div.test:nth-child(4n) works!

Comment: Ok so I precise that in some case, it works well, sometimes it doesn't recognize which one is the fourth element, so the nth-child(4n) work on the second one or another. This is working well if I don't use ng-repeat. I don't know why or what may I have missed but in my case it's not working.

Comment: Could you prepare an isolated example that recreates this issue?

Comment: Maybe you have some ng-show on elements in ng-repeat? So that element you think is second, is, in fact, 4th (because there are two hidden ones before it)