# CSS selector for :last-child in a subset selection

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

assuming i have a structure like this (and **can't** modify it):

```
<ul>
    <li class="common">   <p>First A</p>   </li>
    <li class="common">   <p>Second A</p>   </li>
    <li class="common">   <p>Third A</p> </li>
    <li class="common">   <p><b>SELECT ME</b></p>   </li>
    <li>   <p>First B</p>   </li>
    <li>   <p>Second B</p>   </li>
    <li>   <p>...</p>   </li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to select the last element with class "common"? (in this case the fourth element)

First i tried selecting a subset with:

```
.common{
    background: red;
}
```

and it worked correctly. So i tried selecting last-child of them, with:

```
.common:last-child{
    background: green;
}
```

but not luck. i also would like to avoid adding a class for that element.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seLm589s/3/)

EDIT: i simplified classes and selectors to make it cleaner

Comment: I think. It is not possible by pure css.

Comment: can't you use `li:nth-child(4)` ?

Comment: @Akshay as i said, just in this case is the fourth element, i can't know his index for sure, that's why i needed :last-child. thanks anyway

Comment: yep, that can be easily done with js, i know. but i was looking for a pure css solution, thanks anyway

Comment: Ok, one minute please

Comment: You're probably looking for `nth-match` (which doesn't exist yet in many browsers). See http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#the-nth-match-pseudo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nth-child doesn't respond to class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428676/nth-child-doesnt-respond-to-class)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to select the last element with class "common"?

No, not with a CSS selector without modifying the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

what about

```html
.common:last-of-type {
  background: green;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use JavaScript or jQuery

```
$('custom').prev().css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score -2):

If your not against a JS route you could do this

```
$('li.common.custom').first().prev('.common').css('background','yellow');
```

It finds the first element that has both .common and .custom classes and then goes to the previous element. So its technically the last element that only has .common

https://jsfiddle.net/89z20341/

Is the structure going to stay exactly as you have coded it? eg with the bold tags on the element you want to select?

if so could you just do this

```
.common p b{
background: green;
display:block;
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/seLm589s/4/

Comment: Comment to downvoters: this code is fine. With CSS OP can't make it.

Comment: But question not about js/jQuery solutions. Using js it is trivial to do.

Comment: nope, that bold was just to underline the element. and the style i want to apply is on the .common element, not his children