# CSS class and nth-child() selection with odd/even wrong index

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am using nth-child() a lot times – but now i'm confused about the behavior. I have a wrapper element (id=content) and a lot child elements (class=el). When this is the only content in the wrapper everything is fine. When i place a div (without class) before the "el" objects the ordering of nth-child(odd/even) is wrong.

```
#content {
    background:rgb(200,200,200);
}

.el {
    height:20px;
    background:grey;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.el:nth-child(odd) {
    background:green;
}

.el:nth-child(even) {
    background:red;
}

<div id="content">
    <div></div> (or <i>, <span>, ... any element)
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
</div>
```

I set up an JSFiddle example for that: https://jsfiddle.net/5p2uh5e5/1/ (first line should be green). If you remove the div before the "el" objects the ordering is right. Even if you place a second object of **any** type before the "el" objects.

How can i just select the "el"-Divs with odd/even by CSS?

Comment: Well, i cannot see any mistake on Fiddle...

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428676/nth-child-doesnt-respond-to-class

Comment: I disagree with the choice of duplicate... that one is mostly concentrated on a misunderstanding on how jsfiddle works. There are better duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo classes match elements not classes. When you use it with a class the class acts like a filter. So to take your jsFiddle example:

```
<div id="content">
    <div>xxx</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
</div>
#content {
    background:rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
.el {
    height:20px;
    background:grey;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.el:nth-child(odd) {
    background:green;
}
.el:nth-child(even) {
    background:red;
}
```

The first div without a class is the first child element of the parent div with class content, and it has the index of one (since pseudo classes start at 1) which is odd. Your `.el:nth-child(odd)` rule *is not applied*, because while the child is odd, it doesn't have the class `el`, so it's not applied. Having the `.el` on this pseudo class has made it act like a filter.

The next div, the first one with the class `el` is the *second* child, its index is two, so it's even, and the `.el:nth-child(even)` selector is applied and the background is red. And so and and so forth.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I understand that. Why have i never noticed that?! So there is no plain CSS solution for that - i have to each the Objects with jQuery and mark them via classnames. Is that right? Thanks!

Comment: @KevinLieser There is a solution in CSS if you know how many elements are before the first `el` one.

Comment: Yeah, thats right - but i do not know how many elements are before.

Comment: Hm, shame... And you also don't know for sure if they are divs or not? If you're certain they're not divs, you can use `nth-of-type`.

Comment: No. The content comes out of a CMS. Thanks!

Comment: @KevinLieser Then put all the `.el` divs inside a subcontainer of their own. I've updated my own answer, if you care to take a look.

Comment: Thanks! I'll use the JS solution i've posted because wrapping the elements will cause less freedom in my CMS (the wrapper has also to be created in the CMS - i want to avoid that)

Answer (score 2):

If you know the number of elements before the first `.el` one, you can target only the `.el` ones by writing `2n+x` for odd and `2n+y` for even, where x is that number plus 1 and y is the number plus 2.

So if you have 2 elements, you get `2n+3` for odd and `2n+4` for even.

```css
#content {
    background:rgb(200,200,200);
}

.el {
    height:20px;
    background:grey;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.el:nth-child(2n+3) { /* the number is the amount of unstyled elements before the first .el plus 1 */
    background:green;
}

.el:nth-child(2n+4) { /* and here, the amount plus 2 */
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div>nothing</div> <!-- note, two elements inserted -->
    <div>nothing</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
</div>
```

Edit: if you don't know the number of inserted elements, a possible solution might be to put all the `.el` divs into a container of their own.

```css
#content {
  background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
.el {
  height: 20px;
  background: grey;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
/* Note: more specific selector */
#content > div > .el:nth-child(odd) {
  background: green;
}
#content > div > .el:nth-child(even) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div>nothing</div> <!-- note, two elements inserted -->
  <div>nothing</div>
  <div>              <!-- and a new container for the els -->
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit 2: If that's not possible, one other possibility could be to target each individual `.el` separately. For instance, `:not(.el) + .el` targets the first `.el`, `:not(.el) + .el + .el + .el` targets the third, etc.

The restriction here is that you must know beforehand how many `.el` elements there will be at most. In this example, it will work for up to 10. If there may be more, you will have to use more (and longer) selectors.

```css
#content {
    background:rgb(200,200,200);
}

.el {
    height:20px;
    background:grey;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

#content .el {
  background:red;
}

#content :not(.el) + .el,
#content :not(.el) + .el + .el + .el,
#content :not(.el) + .el + .el + .el + .el + .el,
#content :not(.el) + .el + .el + .el + .el + .el + .el + .el,
#content :not(.el) + .el + .el + .el + .el + .el + .el + .el + .el + .el
{
    background:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div>nothing</div> <!-- note, two elements inserted -->
    <div>nothing</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
</div>
```

And yet another solution could be to start counting at the end, by using `nth-last-child`.

This one has as a restriction that you need to know if the number of `.el` divs is odd or even. This example assumes it's even (because there were 6 in the original code); if it's an odd number you will have to change the styles around.

```css
#content {
    background:rgb(200,200,200);
}

.el {
    height:20px;
    background:grey;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.el:nth-last-child(even) {
    background:green;
}

.el:nth-last-child(odd) {
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div>nothing</div> <!-- note, two elements inserted -->
    <div>nothing</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
    <div class="el">Test 1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @KevinLieser I added two more solutions. Imperfect as they are, one of them may suit your needs. (Haven't found a perfect solution yet, sorry.)

Answer (score 0):

With plain CSS it will not work just to select the specified class elements with nth-child so i made a small jQuery script for adding odd/even classnames to the elements. In CSS - for sure - i've replaced the nth-child(odd/even) with the classnames .odd/.even. Thanks everybody!

```
$('.el').each(function(index) {
    if ((index + 1) %2 == 1) { $(this).addClass('odd'); }
    else { $(this).addClass('even'); }
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Well, i found one solution, just reverse the handling, make:

```
.el:nth-child(even) {
    background:green;
}

.el:nth-child(odd) {
    background:red;
}
```

that will solve your problem....

Comment: Sorry, for sure i can reverse odd/even but there are more complex layouts out there in the whole world...Your solution also does not solve the problem when objects before changing.