# nth-child(odd) not working properly when change class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I keep some elements inside one container. For better visibility odd elements have other background color. Sometimes I need to filter elements with conditions, so unwanted elements I move to another class, but it seems nth-child keep old state. Even if I make it dynamic with jQuery still it keeping old state.

I would prefer keep used and unused elements in same container - if I separate them and change filters, need to sort visible elements again.

```
jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ex4740n2/5/
```

Have you any ideas how to solve it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  Please don't ignore the rules.  But I'm guessing your problem is that you think `nth-child ` is a class selector - it's not, it's an element selector: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428676/nth-child-doesnt-respond-to-class

Comment: The elements are only hidden. They still exist, so they are still considered part of the even/odd indexes.

Comment: I put the code, check jsfiddle link.
@Pete But yes, I was thinking it's a class selector.

Comment: @Synchro.  The main bit of the above statement is **in the question itself** -  Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by @Pete:

```
But I'm guessing your problem is that you think nth-child is a class selector - it's not, it's an element selector
```

So, if it not possible to make it by only css, make it using JS. Iterate visible elements and change background color.

```
var visibled = $(".item");

for (var i = 0; i < visibled.length; i += 2) {
  $(visibled[i]).css("background-color", "rgba(190, 255, 196, 1)");
  $(visibled[i + 1]).css("background-color", "");
}
```