# Select child elements multiple levels down the tree

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to select an element in css only in the case when a parent element higher up the tree has a specific class that is added by user action.

```
<div class="special-mode">
  <div>
    ...n divs...
      <div>Element I want to select</div>
  </div
</div>
```

I looked up how to select this in css and apart from using something like LESS or SASS, the only solution I found was to just grind it out and use a selector for each level of the tree, like

```
.class > * > * > * > * > div {}
```

Is this really the only way to do it? This syntax gets a bit out of control after a few tiers and just seems like a bad solution.

This is for a browser extension that modifies the style of existing webpages with css, so I'm limited in the tools I can use.

Comment: can you add a class to the element selected?

Comment: The accepted answer here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428676/nth-child-doesnt-respond-to-class) should solve your problem.