# nth-child selector not applying correctly when updating classes via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

**I am trying to track the center of a carousel where the elements can be dynamically fully replaced when looping**. With the full element replacement in mind, simply watching for the index to change and adding an `active` class causes a moment of jank while the styles and transitions apply after the carousel has already moved, producing a poor effect.

To overcome this I decided to use CSS to target the 2nd out of 3 elements so that regardless of how the change occurs, the centre of the three should always be targeted via css. Hoever, this isn't working as expected since the nth-child doesn't appear to recalculate when I change the targetted set of elements via JavaScript.

I have reduced the example to find that the `nth-child` css rule I'm using doesn't appear to be recalculated when changing the set of `active` elements using JavaScript.

For example:

set of five elements, three of which have the additional `active` class. Targeting `nth-child(3n+2)` to aim at the middle of the three active classes at all times.

On a button press, a javascript function removes the first active class and applies it to the next non-active element instead.

Expected: the new centre element should be selected by the `nth-child` css selector
Actual: the css rules remain applied to the same element and do not get updated with what should be the new position.

Visually, the effect looks like this:

Before button press:

[image: Initial state with correct nth-child selected (red)]

After button press:

[image: After first buttno press, first active class has been removed and avtive has been added to the next non-active element. Expect nth-child to select the middle of the new trio]

Here's my test case code, It's a simple as I can get it and replicates exactly the behaviour I'm seeing in my real-world case.

```js
// extremely crude but always have 3 active blocks and shift them by 1 on each button press, n.b. it doesn't wrap so it'll just break if you go off the end.
nav = e => {
  var active = document.querySelectorAll('.stuff.active');

  var first = active[0];
  var last = active[2];
  first.classList.remove('active');

  document.querySelector('.active + :not(.active)').classList.add('active');

}
```

```css
.list-of-stuff {
  height: 450px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
}

.stuff {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}

.active {
  background-color: green;
}

.active:nth-child(3n+2) {
  background-color: red;
}

button {
  display: block;
  background: orange;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="nav()">go</button>

  <div class="list-of-stuff">
    <div class="stuff active"></div>
    <div class="stuff active"></div>
    <div class="stuff active"></div>
    <div class="stuff"></div>
    <div class="stuff"></div>
    <div class="stuff"></div>
    <div class="stuff"></div>
    <div class="stuff"></div>
    <div class="stuff"></div>
    <div class="stuff"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Live example:

https://jsbin.com/qeyoyux/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nth-child doesn't respond to class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428676/nth-child-doesnt-respond-to-class) and [Can I combine :nth-child() or :nth-of-type() with an arbitrary selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector)

Comment: Oh you might be right, I didn't come across that while searching