# css nth-child() of a subclass not Working

Tags: css, css-selectors

I just want to format the "visibility" element differently. It doesn't seem to work with `nth-child`.
Can someone tell me why it doesn't work. Or reveal another solution.

many thanks

```css
.owl-stage div.visibility:nth-child(1){
  background: blue;
}
.owl-stage div.visibility:nth-child(2){
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="owl-stage">
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item visibility">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item visibility">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item visibility">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item visibility">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="test">The paragraph.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nth-child` only selects the child count, not the class. So technically the first `.visibility` is the 7th child. And there's no such thing called `nth-class`

But you can still achieve that by relative selector `+`:

```css
/* nth-class(1) */
.owl-stage div:not(.visibility) + .visibility {
  background: blue;
}


/* nth-class(2) */
.owl-stage div:not(.visibility) + .visibility + .visibility {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="owl-stage">
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item visibility">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item visibility">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item visibility">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item visibility">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="test">The paragraph.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**You need to specify `n`**

```
.owl-stage div.visibility:nth-child(1n){
 background: blue;
}
.owl-stage div.visibility:nth-child(2n){
 background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`nth-child()` simply looks at the siblings of `.owl-stage div`. It cannot filter classes like `visibility`. For ideas on filtering by nth-class maybe see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428676/nth-child-doesnt-respond-to-class).

In your case you could use 7th or 8th child as below:

```css
.owl-stage div.visibility:nth-child(7) {
  background: blue;
}
.owl-stage div.visibility:nth-child(8) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="owl-stage">
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item visibility">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item visibility">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item visibility">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item visibility">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="owl-item">The paragraph.</div>
  <div class="test">The paragraph.</div>
</div>
```